# Django form widget: How can I set max value to a value on the database for each item?

Tags: django, forms, widget

```
class CustomerOrderForm(ModelForm):
quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'min':0,'max':,'value':0,'type':'number','style':'max-width: 3em'}))
class Meta: 
    model = Cart
    fields = ('__all__')
```

Each item has its own purchasing limits so I want to go to the database and get the purchasing limit for that item and set that as the 'max'. How can do I do it on django forms?

I know for html, it's like this, but I have a dynamic value that I need to get from the DB:

```
label for="zip_code">Zip Code:</label>
    <input type="text" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" placeholder="Five digit zip code" pattern="[0-9]{5}" maxlength="5" required>
```

Comment: Just pass through the value as context in your view from the model object and then do `maxlength={{context}}` in your html form.

Comment: That doesn't work for the widget... I get an error saying:     quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'min':0,'max':{{ item.limit }},'value':0,'type':'number','style':'max-width: 3em'}))
NameError: name 'item' is not defined

Comment: Not in the widget, in the HTML in your template.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set/update your max in the init function since your max is dependent on an instance. Something like this.

```
class CustomerOrderForm(ModelForm):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'min':0, 'value':0,'type':'number','style':'max-width: 3em'}))
    class Meta: 
    model = Cart
    fields = ('__all__')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['quantity'].widget.attrs.update(
            {'max': self.instance.quantity},
        )
```

Note that this check is only done in the init when rendering the HTML. You probably want to do some validation in the clean() or save() function, when the form is submitted.

Edit:
I didn't read your question properly.

```
self.instance
```

is referring to a Cart model. But you probably want to iterate over your items.

Comment: Do you have to add the instance to views.py or is instance just a variable? Where would you declare instance? I'm confused about how django knows which instance it is.

Comment: Modelform accepts an existing instance by the keyword instance, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I had the modelformset written incorrectly and the code you gave me works now. Thanks for your help.